# safest way to let users with no login to delete mysql entry

Tags: php, mysql

so heres the problem,

i have an if() statement that determines whether a user has visited my site before, if they have then they have an option for removing their record from the database. Problem is, i cant see any safe way to do this. They are public users.

Im just confused, id have to do it with ajax im guessing?!?

Comment: Pardon me, but what security does ajax add? Also, how does this system work, could you show something?

Comment: What are you checking in the `if` statement?

Comment: @Damien Pirsy ajax would somewhat mask the method of deleting the entry and showing the results without page reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user visits your site, store a cookie on their computer containing a large random number, preferably encrypted and a smaller id number. When storing the record in your database, include that same large random number, again preferably encrypted (both while in your database and in transit) and the id number.

When a user wants to delete their record, they need only submit the id number and the large random number (preferably encrypted) that are stored on their computer, along with a flag indicating that they want to delete the record. (Of course they should not be doing this manually, you will need to write code that handles the dirty work.) Then, your server will look at the record with the specified id number, check if the large random number matches the one stored, and if so delete the record.

Comment: understood, but what if the user wipes their cookies before returning to the website?

Comment: If the user wipes their cookies, and you don't want to ask them for a password, there is no way to distinguish one user from another, except  sneaky things like [supercookies](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424053111903480904576508382675931492.html) or flash cookies that you probably don't want your website associated with. If the user deletes their cookies, it means that they don't want you to know who they are-- it would kind of defeat the purpose of giving them control of their data if you violate that expectation.

Comment: i agree with the supercookies & flash cookies statement, its not something that i'd like to use. Thanks for your answer, i think this is the safest and most approachable method i could use.